# Reduce Calls to Bing Translator Api

Tags: bing-translator-api

I have text in 5 Languages: English, German, Spanish, Italian and French. I have to translate text from other languages to english. The Language auto-detect function detects the language, but it costs as 1 call to the translator. Since i'm using the free tier, this isn't feasible. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify 'from' in your Translate request, Detect will be run automatically before the translation starts.

Comment: Yes, but would that not count as a call to the api? to detect the language?

Comment: No, it'll only count as a translate call.